What is the minimum $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $n\tan(\frac{\pi}{n})<\frac{101\pi}{100}$?
This is the original question:

For a circle inscribed in a regular n-sided polygon. What is the
minimum $n$ so that:
$\frac{Area_{shaded}}{Area_{circle}}<\frac{1}{100}$?
Where the shaded area is the area of the n-sided polygon excluding the
circular area.

This is my work:
Let the radius of the inscribed circle be 1. We create a isosceles triangle with the centre of the circle O and a side of the polygon. We know that the angle formed in O is equal to $\frac{2\pi}{n}$, so $S_{shaded}=n\tan(\frac{\pi}{n})-\pi$. Hence, $\frac{Area_{shaded}}{Area_{circle}}=\frac{n\tan(\frac{\pi}{n})-\pi}{\pi}<\frac{1}{100}$.
We end up with $n\tan(\frac{\pi}{n})<\frac{101\pi}{100}$, which I don't know how to solve as it has the varible $n$ inside the tangent.

I think that $n=1$ it's clearly the minimum $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that verify the inequality, I don't know if your attempt is correct..

@SigmaAlgebra we need $n\geq3$ so that we really have a polygon.

Here's an approximation that makes it easy to find the solution.
For small $z$ we have $\tan z = z + z^3/3 + \cdots$.  Assume that's exactly true - then you have
$$n \tan {\pi \over n} \approx n + n \times {1 \over 3} \left( {\pi \over n} \right) ^3 = n + \left( {\pi^3/3} \right) n^{-2}$$
And $(\pi^3/3) n^{-2} < \pi/100$ can be solved for $n$ to get $n  > \pi \sqrt{100/3} \approx 18.14$.
Then you can check that $18 \tan (\pi/18) > 101\pi/100$ and $19 \tan (\pi/19) < 101\pi/100$ by direct computation.
(Alternately you can just check $n = 3, 4, 5, \ldots$ until you get there.)
